# How to make custom tags valid on PHPStorm?

Tags: html, tags, phpstorm

There are some valid tags `<esi:include dca="esi" onerror="continue" src="{{ esi_bottom_url }}"/>` in some HTML files but PHPStorm reports them as bugs. How to make it not report them as errors?

[image: Errors]

https://www.w3.org/TR/esi-lang/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/caching.1012/b14046/esi.htm#i633302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- <kbd>Right mouse click</kbd> on the tag and choose `Add [tag] to custom html tags`, where `[tag]` is the chosen phrase.
- disable tag checking in `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `HTML`  -> `Unknown tag` or change the severity of the report.

You can also just add the required `http://www.edge-delivery.org/esi/1.0` namespace to the `<html>` tag, see [ESI docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/esi-lang/), e.g.:

```
<html xmlns:esi="http://www.edge-delivery.org/esi/1.0">
```